# Variable not working in cURL CURLOPT_URL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, calendly

I'm trying to use a variable as URL in a cURL GET request but it's not working.

$data is sent via ajax from the other page. If I echo $data once it's been declared and before $curl is declared, the URL I want to use appears (`https://api.calendly.com/event_types/d5d0d786-54b8-4e85-83ce-5b5d853957fa` ).

But using $data in the cURL request just won't work. If I replace the $data variable with the URL as a string - `"https://api.calendly.com/event_types/d5d0d786-54b8-4e85-83ce-5b5d853957fa"`, it works fine and returns the value I want from the response ('scheduling_url'), so I can't see why the $data variable that contains the same thing won't work.

Is the variable somehow not being passed properly into the cURL request? Any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

$data = isset($_REQUEST['myData'])?$_REQUEST['myData']:"";
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => $data,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $response_json = json_decode($response, true);
  echo $response_json['resource']['scheduling_url'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `$data` include the full URL or just the parameter you want to send

Comment: perhaps use `urldecode( $_REQUEST['myData'] )`

Comment: Hi @NigelRen - yes it contains the full URL `https://api.calendly.com/event_types/d5d0d786-54b8-4e85-83ce-5b5d853957fa`

Comment: Hi @ProfessorAbronsius thanks for the suggestion, how would I incorporate that into my code please? (sorry I'm still a PHP noob)

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL => urldecode( $_REQUEST['myData'] )`

Answer (score 2):

Solved it - turned out there was some additional white space at the end of the stored $data URL which I cleaned using trim().